# How to discover running WCF Data Services using Android?

Tags: android, wcf-data-services, service-discovery

My Android application connects to a WCF data service hosted in a Windows Service using [odata4j](https://bintray.com/odata4j/odata4j). The communication works well when a specified URL is provided where the service can be found. 
However, I need to modify the application to discover the service addresses (multiple computer can run the service in the LAN).
How can I discover these service addresses? Obviously other than trying to connect to each address on LAN using a for loop with a try catch block. Any Android feature for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there isn't. I created an AsyncTask that runs multiple threads to paralelly discover the LAN addresses. It is not pretty but sometimes there is no alternative.